# how to suppress mysql error java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, rss, duplicates

I'm trying to automate the addition of links from an RSS feed to a mySQL table.  I want to take input from the feed every hour, but there are usually links that I have already grabbed still present on the RSS page when I reference it again.

I've got java code that works the first time, but when I try to add a duplicate file to the sql table I get an exception.  I thought that mySQL would just ignore and pass over the duplicates, as I'm using the `MUL` key on the field name in question, but I get an exception instead.

Any ideas on how to get this rolling?  I don't want duplicates, and I don't want duplicates to stop other new things from being added.

Thanks!

Comment: Check for a possible duplicate before you insert?

Comment: You probably should provide the insert statement you're using. You need to add a precheck condition to check for duplicates in the table before insert or change your prinary key and unique constraints to allow for duplicates on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Yep, that got it.  I should have looked there first, thanks for the help and for not calling me slacker!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` if you want to keep the old value instead of replacing it.